# How to export sites from Google Search Console?

Tags: google-search-console

How do I export sites from Google Webmaster Tools / Search Console so I can import them into Bing Webmaster Tools?

Help appreciated.

Comment: Even if you export a list of sites from Google, Bing only allows you to add them one at a time.

Comment: I think @Massimiliano's answer covers it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as far as I know the 2 "console" are completely separate. 
You have to create each property in Bing. 
You log in in Bing here:
[bing.com/webmaster/home/mysites](https://www.bing.com/webmaster/home/mysites)

then add your property by inserting the URL and follow instruction. You will have to download then upload a file to your website, quite similar to Google.

Answer (score 0):

Bing Webmaster is testing an option to import verified sites from Google Search Console. You can find the option in your Bing Webmaster homepage (screenshot below).

Your imported site will be verified in Bing Webmaster (no additional verification process) and you will be mapped to an equivalent role for the imported site in Bing Webmaster.

[image]